# How to get the name of a function reference?

Tags: reflection, dart

Consider the following

### Dart Code

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
  Function  pointer   = ((new Random().nextInt(100) % 2) == 0 ? someClass.fooMethod : someClass.barMethod);

  print('$pointer');
}
```

#### Output

`Closure 'barMethod$0' of Instance of 'MyClass'`

([dartpad here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/fc44583f7dedd78cb4973b3842966735))

### Question

Assuming `SomeClass` is immutable, how do I get this to instead print simply `barMethod` or `fooMethod`? (also acceptable would be `SomeClass.barMethod` or `SomeClass.fooMethod`)

Comment: I'd be curious what the use case is. The solution if it existed would only work in the standalone VM (not well on the web and not on all in Flutter).

Comment: @matanlurey my particular use-case is for backend-only server code, so the standalone VM is fine

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using reflection, although this can be expensive if you intend to run it in the browser with dart2js. This snippet works:

```dart
import 'dart:math' show Random;
import 'dart:mirrors';

void main() {
  MyClass  myClass = new MyClass();

  // Rather than (x % 2 == 0) you could do x.isEven,
  // but there's also Random.nextBool()
  Function pointer = new Random().nextBool() ? myClass.foo : myClass.bar;

  ClosureMirror cm = reflect(pointer) as ClosureMirror;
  print(MirrorSystem.getName(cm.function.simpleName));

  pointer();
}

class MyClass {
  void foo() {}
  void bar() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the existence of both `.isEven` and `.nextBool()`!

Comment: This is a great start, thank you! It kinda breaks down if `foo` or `bar` are declared as static, though... I realize that wasn't in the original question, but is there any solution that handles both statics and non-statics? https://dartpad.dartlang.org/05077d057b0ae6ea5fcba412d7c2a375

Comment: Are these method names statically known (compile-time)? You could make a `Map<Function, String>` which is not ideal, but reflection isn't ideal either

Comment: They're statically known by the compiler in the sense that they're literally declared as `static`, but otherwise, no. I wouldn't want to try to manually maintain a list of methods hardcoded in a map. It needs to be automatic in some way.